# Can I still use PHP's image/png header after performing Javascript on the DOM?

Tags: javascript, php, dom, header

I have my Linux server setup in htaccess so that if it goes to an image (.png) URL that doesn't exist, it executes a PHP script that sets the header to `header('Content-Type: image/png');` and creates an image with `imagepng` so that it displays something based on the URL.

I have an image filter, but it is made in Javascript. Is there any way I can use this same scheme but have it filter through the image filter in Javascript afterward, and still output a png and retain the header of `image/png`?

My knowledge is that PHP is server-side and Javascript is client-side, so the server-side code is already executed, so it can't be edited by the DOM (client side) and have it still retain the image/png header.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't explain what you want the js to do, but in theory you could post-process on the client side by creating an output containing both html with the image and the js to process it which would keep the header.  It would look something like this:

Create your png file

```
createpng(..., fu/bar.png,...,...);
```

Set your header

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
```

Create output string containing both html and js (getting the ' and " can be a bit tricky)

```
$output = '
<img src="fu/bar.png">
<script>
//add js filter script here
</script>
';
```

then echo your $output in whatever page is displaying the view (index.php?)

```
<?= $output ?>
```

Comment: The extension on the URL is .png, so that means it would need to be a png no matter what site the image is on. I think If I include any other html output or js, it would forget about the header content type, and things would go wrong. It's similar to if I set the header to png, and echoed a short string. The image would no longer display, and instead output glitchy looking text.

Comment: I see what your question/issue is now.  Don't png files have a property for embedded internal scripts and external script calls?  I don't know if browsers would allow it to execute, but perhaps embedding a processing script/call within each png file itself might be a work-around.  Or just figure out which combination of php image funcs do the processing you want

Answer (score 0):

No you can not , but there a lot of php image effects plugins you can use

Comment: I'm trying to find xBRZ. I have only been able to find it for Javascript.